# Is adding a "Total" description redundant in spreadsheets?

Tags: tables

I'm making a spreadsheet for the PC I'm building, and I wondered if the **Total** description at the bottom of the `Price` column is necessary.

In terms of user experience, is it already understood and redundant? Should I omit the **Total** description?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unless there is some visual indication that the given value is a summation, I don't think the presence of the "Total" label is redundant. Furthermore, the presence of the "Total" label helps the reader understand that it isn't a value missing the item name.

[image]

Usually subtotals have a top border and grand totals have a top border with a double bottom border, but this may be locale dependant. Even then, a label helps the reader immediately understand what the number represents, especially if there's multiple totals on the sheet.

[image]